# I didn't receive push notification on iPhone using cordova plugin

Tags: xcode, cordova, plugins, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app

I integrated cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-push "PushPlugin" in my app, but after I send a notification, I didn't receive it with alert or badge or sound, nothing.
The registration has been successfully because gave the token correctly. 
I also generated the push certificate (Apple Development IOS Push Services) and exported it in p12 format.
On Xcode I setted push notification button.
Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases for your error.

1. When you call `Push.Init`, there is sth missing. Folling example is my own.

   ```
    Push.init({
     ios: {
       senderID: "XXXXXXXXXX",
       gcmSandbox: true,
       alert: true,
       badge: true,
       sound: true
     }
    }
   ```
2. In https://developers.google.com/mobile/add, you have to add the platform ios and sign up your .p12 certificate in ios project of google console.